# Handle click events from large grid of Buttons?

Tags: vb.net

Okay so I have multitude buttons on a form, and I want a label to display a certain number based on which button is clicked.  For example, if any of the buttons in row one of the buttons is clicked, the label would display 10.  If any of the buttons from row two are clicked, the label would display 17, etc.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Handles` keyword to handle multiple events, from multiple objects, using one `Sub` method, for instance:

```
Private Sub Row1ButtonHandler(ByRef obj As Object, ByRef ea As EventArgs) _
    Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click
    Label1.Text = "1"
End Sub

Private Sub Row2ButtonHandler(ByRef obj As Object, ByRef ea As EventArgs) _
    Handles Button4.Click, Button5.Click, Button6.Click
    Label1.Text = "17"
End Sub
```

As you can see, each of those handler methods will now be called any time any of the buttons in their row are clicked.

However, it may be easier to programmatically set-up the event handlers using the `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` functions:

```
For c As Int32 = 0 to 10
    Dim btn As Control = Page.FindControl("Button" & c)
    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf MyEventHandler
Next c
```

Note that I have used a generic `Control` here and have assumed that you are looking at a webpage, but you could be more specific by using, perhaps, a LinkButton control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handles for all button and fetch button in sender value and then add your logic.
May be help you...